# categorical ui-search in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, semantic-ui

I am trying to make a local category search box using Semantic UI in ember, Here is what I have done so far:

```js
//component nav-bar.js
import Component from '@ember/component';

export default Component.extend({
  searchables: [
    { category: 'Country', title: 'India' },
    { category: 'Country', title: 'Germany' },
    { category: 'Currency', title: 'USD' }
  ]
```

```
//component nav-bar.hbs

    <div class="item">
      {{#ui-search class="fluid" source=searchables onSearchQuery=(action (mut query)) onSelect=(action (mut selected))}}
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="prompt">
        <div class="results"></div>
      {{/ui-search}}
    </div>
```

This is resulting in a simple search box instead of a  local categorical search. What should I do to get a  categorical search box instead?

Comment: The ember docs don't seem to show this, but there appears to be a `type` property on search. What happens if you add `type=category` or add category to the `class` property on `{{ui-search}}`?

Comment: @jrjohnson adding category to class property doesn't change anything but using a `type` property and setting it to `category` shows no results at all.